# Can't login to Heroku CLI

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I can't login to the Heroku CLI. I get the below error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'U:/_netrc'
```

I've determined that my IT department has set up the default Unix user directory to an unmapped network drive. I can't change that part... Can I point CLI to a local path?

Comment: I'm assuming you're running this from you local machine? What does the out put of `heroku` command show?

Comment: CLI to interact with Heroku

VERSION
  heroku/7.30.1 win32-x64 node-v11.14.0

USAGE
  $ heroku [COMMAND]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with run it from GIT BASH cmd